# My automationelement FindFirst/FindAll seems to be very slow. How to improve the performance?

Tags: ui-automation

From a windows application, I read data from another windows application. I traverse and find the elements with FindFirst/Find all. But this is very slow. Is there a way to speed up the performance.
Am isung the exact automationIdproperty still it is very slow

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 3):

What's the TreeScope you're using in your code? Searches from AutomationElement.RootElement and with TreeScope.Descendants can be extremely slow. You should use a closer element, and if possible, define TreeScope.Children. This will significantly speed up your performance.

In addition, note that if you're querying the AutomationElements themselves multiple times, you will benefit from caching the element on your first request, and always access its cached properties and patterns.

Comment: System.Windows.Automation is a lorry full of shit. I call AutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition) and for returning a ridiculous amount of 30 children Microsoft's crappy code takes incredible 1000 ms on a very fast computer!! Additionally the whole crap is not even threadsafe! It is a shame how UIAutomation has been implemented.

Comment: The solution to slow performance is to use the new IUIAutomationElement COM interface (since Windows 7) instead of the old System.Windows.Automation C# interface. After that the code will be running LIGHTNING fast! Apart from that the new interface offers much more patterns and Microsoft is extending it continously. In the Windows 10 SDK several patterns and properties have been added.